# Convert google maps urls to maps api markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a huge list of Google map urls which link to exact locations of restaurants.

**Examples:**

- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=gran+bar+dazon&hl=en&ll=-34.560011,-58.40847&spn=0.069836,0.129604&sll=-34.551741,-58.432331&sspn=0.00873,0.016201&doflg=ptk&hq=gran+bar+dazon&t=m&z=13&iwloc=A
- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=the+library+lounge+buenos+aires&hl=en&ll=-34.602976,-58.361778&spn=0.0349,0.064802&sll=-34.560011,-58.40847&sspn=0.069836,0.129604&doflg=ptk&hq=the+library+lounge&hnear=Buenos+Aires,+Autonomous+City+of+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina&t=m&z=14&iwloc=A
- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=isabel+bar+buenos+aires&hl=en&ll=-34.541914,-58.431473&spn=0.139703,0.259209&sll=-34.602976,-58.361778&sspn=0.0349,0.064802&doflg=ptk&hq=isabel+bar+buenos+aires&radius=15000&t=m&z=12&iwloc=A

I am creating a web page which will display a subset of those restaurants on a single map.

The problem I have is that I can't find a scriptable way to convert these urls in to query strings which I can pass into the Google maps javascript api to make markers.

Answer (score 0):

The `ll` parameter in the url is the Lattitude and Longtitude of the restaurant. If you parse the url you can get the position of the restaurant and create the markers after in JS using this data. I use RichMarkers and do it like this:

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lo);
var marker = new RichMarker({
                    position: location.getLatLng(),
                    map: me.map,
                    content: 'some content'
                });
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: Hi Mat, Unfortunately the the 'll' parameter is not the exact location or the restaurant. It seems that the 'll' is a rough location at which  Google searches for the address.

Comment: Well it's the lat and lon of the restaurant. If you want to get the addres you can do the reverse geocoding (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) But I guess from the url you can't obtain the place details...
Probably you can try Google Places, with the data from the URL (search string and lat, lon) you could obtain the place.. check here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search